# MySQL Joining two tables replacing ID with user name

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with JOIN, INNER JOIN based on two tables as below
I was trying to JOIN them with no result actually (got mysql errors)and after few hours i give up
I belive there must be a solution but i think now that i don't understant JOIN - INNER JOIN - or other kind of needed join type.
Is there someone who could help me with this query?

Table 1 - jawe_wpdatatable_8 :

| uzytkownik | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | some data | some data |
| 1 | some data | some data |
| 2 | some data | some data |
| 2 | some data | some data |
| 2 | some data | some data |

table 2 - jawe_users:

| ID | user_nicename | other not important columns... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bart |  |
| 2 | asia |  |
| 3 | bry1 |  |

the result I expect should be like this:

**mysql expected result**

| uzytkownik | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| asia | some data | some data |
| bart | some data | some data |
| asia | some data | some data |
| asia | some data | some data |
| asia | some data | some data |

I want to replace 2,1 and other numbers of 'uzytkownik' with coresponding with them user_nicename

I was trying to figure it out basing on [MYSQL: join multiple tables - replace multiple userID's with user names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111277/mysql-join-multiple-tables-replace-multiple-userids-with-user-names)
With no result. I don't get it.

---

OK. so I figured it out and for me working query (on real table) is

```
SELECT r.data,
       r.nrpartii,
       r.nazwadzianiny,
       r.skladdzianiny,
       r.nazwamaszyny,
       r.rzad,
       r.nrmaszyny,
       r.starynrmaszyny,
       r.nruiglenia,
       r.wydzigla,
       r.waga,
       r.uwagipredkoscmaszyny,
       u1.user_nicename
FROM jawe_wpdatatable_8 AS r
inner join jawe_users as u1 on u1.ID = r.uzytkownik
```

Tested in sql console

Comment: you forgot to put your attempted query and the errors you get so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a simple join:

```
SELECT 
  j.`user_nicename` AS uzytkownik, 
  k.`column2`,
  k.`column3`
FROM
  `jawe_users` j 
  JOIN `jawe_wpdatatable_8` k 
    ON k.`uzytkownik` = j.`id`
```

Comment: Please provide a description on why you think this is what is being looked for....

Comment: Because I tried the data in my computer and the result of the query is an exact match with his expected output.

Comment: Maybe you can add a link to a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0)?  In this case your SQL might work, but "what if" OP is starting to say "It does not work" ? You should give as much as possible feedback to the question asker, and with your answer he/she is not helped with the problem: "**but i think now that i don't understant JOIN - INNER JOIN - or other kind of needed join type.**"